# Which type of tile layout is Skype using on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, skype

[image: Skype WideTile]

Are they using [Iconic Tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009(v=vs.105).aspx)? 
If yes, then how are they showing Icon and count on left and Content on right side? On MSDN documentation, the wide iconic tile does not have this type of formatting for icons and content.

Comment: Is it animating the number like Iconic Tiles? If not it could be normal flip tiles. But be aware that Skype is owned my Microsoft and they could use a different SDK.

Comment: On testing the skype app on my phone, It turns out it just use normal Wide Iconic Tile like notification with content on top left, icon and count at bottom right. The image given on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662933(v=vs.105).aspx) is giving little wrong impression about possible layouts

Comment: Well it is certainly possible to create a live tile looking like that if you use the fliptile and let a server/background worker create the image! With Iconic Tiles it is however not.

Answer (score 0):

Tile layout used by Skype seems to be a custom tile layout.

One way to create it would be to create a image with all the content of the tile(except the title "Skype") in your code.

Imagetools library (http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) can be used to create custom png images.Or you may use writable bitmap's render method to save a grid with the contents of the tile in form of a bitmap and convert it to jpeg.

Then use either png or jpeg image as your background image in FlipTileData to create a similar tile.